# How can I create a string using toString?

Tags: r, data.table, tostring

I have a data table with 2 columns: category and priority. I'm classifying the data in the following way using a for loop:

- I check if the priority of the actual value is smaller to the
  previous one.
- I save the value of category in the column "`new`".
- I save the previous value of category in a string on the column
  "`rest`".
- If the priority of the actual value is higher, I do the opposite
  operation.

I've already tried with the functions `paste`, `paste0` and `toString`, but I can't achieve a desired result.

```r
priority <- c(3,2,1,4,5,6,7)
category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")

data.dt <- data.table(priority,category)
data.dt$new <- NA
data.dt$rest <- NA
for (i in 2:nrow(data.dt)){
  if(data.dt$priority[i]<=data.dt$priority[i-1]){
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i]
    data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[i-1])
    }
  else{
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i-1]
    data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[i])
  }
  }
```

This is my result:

```r
   priority category  new rest
1:        3        a <NA> <NA>
2:        2        b    b    a
3:        1        c    c    b
4:        4        d    c    d
5:        5        e    d    e
6:        6        f    e    f
7:        7        g    f    g
```

But I want the following one:

```r
   priority category  new rest
1:        3        a <NA> <NA>
2:        2        b    b    a
3:        1        c    c    a,b
4:        4        d    c    a,b,d
5:        5        e    d    a,b,d,e
6:        6        f    e    a,b,d,e,f
7:        7        g    f    a,b,d,e,f,g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, just add `1:x` sequences (denoted `#`) instead of single values.

```
data.dt$new <- NA
data.dt$rest <- NA

for (i in 2:nrow(data.dt)) {
  if(data.dt$priority[i] <= data.dt$priority[i-1]) {
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i]
    data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[1:(i-1)])  #
  }
  else{
    data.dt$new[[i]] <- data.dt$category[i-1]
    data.dt$rest[[i]] <- toString(data.dt$category[1:i])  #
  }
}
#    priority category  new                rest
# 1:        3        a <NA>                <NA>
# 2:        2        b    b                   a
# 3:        1        c    c                a, b
# 4:        4        d    c          a, b, c, d
# 5:        5        e    d       a, b, c, d, e
# 6:        6        f    e    a, b, c, d, e, f
# 7:        7        g    f a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

Alternatively you could do this without a `for` loop using `diff`. (You don't need to create `NA`s beforehand.)

```
data.dt$new <- 
  with(data.dt, ifelse(c(NA, diff(priority)) < 0, category, c(NA, category)))
```

*Explanation:* `diff` calculates the difference for each value from it's previous value; we apply `ifelse` (which is vectorized `if` and `else`) on condition if `diff` is `< 0`.

```
sl <- c(NA, Map(function(x) toString(data.dt$category[seq(x)]), seq(nrow(data.dt))))
data.dt$rest <- ifelse(c(NA, diff(data.dt$priority)) < 0, sl, sl[-1])

data.dt
#    priority category  new                rest
# 1:        3        a <NA>                  NA
# 2:        2        b    b                   a
# 3:        1        c    c                a, b
# 4:        4        d    c          a, b, c, d
# 5:        5        e    d       a, b, c, d, e
# 6:        6        f    e    a, b, c, d, e, f
# 7:        7        g    f a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

***Update***

To get rid of values in `rest` column appearing in `new` column you could omit `match`es with this code:

```
sc <- Map(function(x) c(data.dt$category[seq(x)]), seq(nrow(data.dt)))
data.dt$rest <- unlist(c(NA, Map(function(x, y) 
  toString(x[is.na(match(x, y))]), sc, data.dt$new)[-1]))
```

*Explanation:* For the `rest` column we want `seq`uences `sc` with length of the actual row which we achieve with `Map`. Because we don't want those values already appearing in `new` column, we `match` `sc` with `data.dt$new` before applying `toString`. The `unlist` gives us a vector because we don't want a column of class list.

Looking into `?Map` reveals it applies successively a `FUN`ction onto the following two objects *in same order*: `Map(FUN, x, y)`. The results are collected in a list. For the fourth elements that would look like this:

```
# Map(FUN, x, y)
(x <- sc[[4]])
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
(y <- data.dt$new[[4]])
# [1] "c"
toString(x[is.na(match(x, y))])  # FUN
# [1] "a, b, d"
```

***Result***

```
data.dt
#   priority category  new             rest
# 1        3        a <NA>             <NA>
# 2        2        b    b                a
# 3        1        c    c             a, b
# 4        4        d    c          a, b, d
# 5        5        e    d       a, b, c, e
# 6        6        f    e    a, b, c, d, f
# 7        7        g    f a, b, c, d, e, g
```

***Data***

```
data.dt <- structure(list(priority = c(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7), category = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf!! What is the second part of the code?

Comment: @Ipa Very welcome, also see update! You probably mean the _Data_ part, it is intended to enable other users to quickly replicate the data needed to run the code.

Comment: Okay, now I understand :)

Comment: If I want to drop the "new" value on the "rest", column in every row, what should I add to de code?

Comment: @Ipa see upate!

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf!! It works! Is it possible to do it use "gsub()"?

Comment: @Ipa You don't need to create `data.dt$rest` twice, just use the update code. There should no need to use `gsub` then. Ok?

Comment: Okay, I'm more used to work with for loops, this expressions are difficult to understand for me. Could you give me a little explanation of how the code works please?

Comment: @Ipa Done so! R is a vectorized language, i.e. you may apply functions on an entire vector instead on each element, thus avoiding loops mostly is more efficient.

Comment: I understand. Although I want to make some modifications on my code, I've just realized that the output of the code is not the desired one. Should I modify this post or open a new one?

Comment: @Ipa maybe it's easier to add the new desired output in an edit first. we could decide after, then in case revert this post to original and open a new one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195338/discussion-between-jay-sf-and-ipa).

Comment: Hi @jay.sf, I'm trying to understand the code you wrote for the "rest" column. I understand the first line, but not the second one when you create the "rest" column.

Comment: hello @jay.sf, thanks! So basically you see which value of column "new" matches with the column "rest" and you delete from it?

Comment: @Ipa yeah, exactly that's happening!

Comment: and why are you creating a vector c(NA, "something") ??

Comment: @Ipa actually it's `c(NA, ("something"[-1]))` , i.e. the first value (`"a"`) is replaced by `NA` since we want it there.